# Is it possible to measure the angle of a surface that is rotating in x/y-axis?

Tags: python, contour, opencv

i am trying to detect the angle of a surface which is rotating in the x or y-axis. Basically as the images below show:
[Straight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5yMU.jpg)

[Rotated around y-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QzCv.jpg)

[Rotated around x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NuAM.jpg)

I am using openCV and Contours to measure the distances and areas of both shapes, but I am stuck when it comes to the angle of rotation.
I was thinking of using the areas of both shapes to somehow make a relation between the change in area and angle of rotation (the areas change depending on which shape is closer/further from the camera).
If any of you have any other ideas or have any sort of experience in this matter, I would be more than happy for your help.

Thank you.

Comment: If you know the size and orientation of the unrotated rectangle, then if you turns only in one dimension, then you can determine the perspective fractional linear equation from the 4 vertices of the non-rotated and rotated rectangle. Then use the fractional linear equation coefficients to determine the sine and cosine of the angles. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection

Answer (score 0):

You can look at measuring the change in the angle of the lines.

- Raw an ROI around Each Shape (or the entire white canvas) and crop out that region to remove any background object.
- Use Edge Detection of OpenCV to detect the Edges (You can use Canny Edge Detector for this step)
- Apply Hough Transform on the Edges to get the straight lines moving across the edge of each shape.
- Separate & Filter out the relevant lines by applying thresholds like minimum & maximum length, etc.
- Find the angle/slope of the lines (A bit of math: `y = mx + c`)
- You can then detect the change in angles/slope of the lines to determine if the figures are tilted or not.

An official tutorial on Hough Line Transform can be found here: [OpenCV Hough Line Transform](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html)