# Detect the angle of a surface in real-time

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

My project is about image detection. I am using 1 camera and have 2 shapes (rectangle and triangle) placed on a flat surface. I have successfully been able to:

- Detect the contours
- Detect the area of the contours
- Make a relation between both areas and the distances, to be able to calculate both distances from the camera
- Calculate the lengths, corner coordinates and the angle of each corner in both shapes

Now I need to calculate the angle of rotation of the whole surface when rotated around the x-axis (up & down), y-axis (left & right) and both axes (oblique). This can be seen in the gif I provided. The default angle (0 degrees) is when the surface is parallel to the camera, and any rotation would mean that an angle around 1 or both axes is present.

[image: Rotations]

P.S When the surface is rotating around both axes (oblique), both angles have to be detected separately. For example, I would get 14° x-axis & 27° y-axis.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The position of the surface relative to the camera, given a reference, should be uniquely defined by 3 Euler angles and 3 offsets, so it's 6 degrees of freedom in total. Each point in the 2D image gives you 2 conditions, so if you track 3 points which don't lie on a line, you should get 6 conditions. With 6 conditions, you should be able to solve for the 6 degrees of freedom. So pick three points you can track, the rest is math.

Comment: If you know the geometry of your plane objects (or if you can define it in your 0 degree setting) you can use opencv solvePnp function to get the object pose. Use the inverse to get the camera pose.

Comment: I've already tried SolvePnP, but I am a bit stuck when it comes to the object points. The 5 pts I am using are the 4 corners of the rectangle and its center. How do i get the real-world coordinates of those pts? I simply don't understand the concept. @Micka

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/detect-the-angle-of-a-surface-in-real-time/5206 and previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68378885/is-it-possible-to-measure-the-angle-of-a-surface-that-is-rotating-in-x-y-axis

Comment: You will either need to know the object points or you have to guess them. E.g. if your initial 0-degree rect is 500x200 pixel size you could try to just set object point 4 to (500,200,0). The 3D coordinate system is quite arbitrary so you could also set the point to (0,500,200) if it is condistent  to the other points. In the end the object points should represent a 2D rectangle in 3D space with an aspect ratio equalling your original rectangle.